# Highcharts bar with negative stack: how to position data labels

Tags: javascript, highcharts, position

I have a population pyramid like this: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2Ht35/).
I want to adjust the distance between the bars and the datalabels. But when I use the `x` parameter, the labels get closer on one side and get more distant on the other side in the chart.

```
$(function () {
    var chart,
        categories = ['0-9', '10-19',
            '20-29', '30-39', '40-49', '50-59', '60-69',
            '70-79', '80-89', '90 +'];
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#container').highcharts({
            chart: {
                type: 'bar'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Population pyramid for Germany, midyear 2010'
            },
            subtitle: {
                text: 'Source: www.census.gov'
            },
            xAxis: [{
                categories: categories,
                reversed: false,
                labels: {
                    step: 1
                }
            }, { // mirror axis on right side
                opposite: true,
                reversed: false,
                categories: categories,
                linkedTo: 0,
                labels: {
                    step: 1
                }
            }],
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: null
                },
                labels: {
                    formatter: function(){
                        return (Math.abs(this.value) / 1000000) + 'M';
                    }
                },
                min: -8000000,
                max: 8000000
            },

            plotOptions: {
                bar: {
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: true,
                        formatter: function() {
                            return Math.round(Math.abs(this.y)/1000) + 'T';
                        },
                        inside: false,
                        x: 10 // <--- This doesn't realy work as I need it to!!!
                    }
                },
                series: {
                    stacking: 'normal'
                }
            },

            tooltip: {
                formatter: function(){
                    return '<b>'+ this.series.name +', age '+ this.point.category +'</b><br/>'+
                        'Population: '+ Highcharts.numberFormat(Math.abs(this.point.y), 0);
                }
            },

            series: [{
                name: 'Male',
                data: [-3630609, -4312120, -5044512, -5107716, -7236736, -5864184, -4456949, -3506268, -1191588, -122814]
            }, {
                name: 'Female',
                data: [3443718, 4090246, 4769441, 4821276, 6854069, 5810335, 4730948, 4354576, 2452173, 482710]
            }]
        });
    });

});
```

I want to stay as native and close to Highcharts as posible. I try to avoid using `useHTML: true` as I need to export it as SVG, which is needed for a pretty fussy script later (and sometimes this caused me trouble in the past). But you may suggest me this anyway, if it isn't possible without it.

Do you know of any way how to accomplish a symmetrical positioning of datalabels on bars with negative stack?

Thanks in advance and best regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use padding, to add space between the label and the bar. Padding up to 8 seems to work well for your case.

```
...
plotOptions: {
    bar: {
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            formatter: function() {
                return Math.round(Math.abs(this.y)/1000) + 'T';
            },
            inside: false,
            padding: 8, // <-- Instead of x
            y: -1 // This is only to beautify
        }
    },
    series: {
        stacking: 'normal'
    }
},
...
```

Unfortunately if you increase the padding too much, the number won't fit into the space anymore, and you'd have to increase the max and min values (like this http://jsfiddle.net/2Ht35/1/).

Comment: This is the most beautiful and convinient answer given.
I started experiemnting with `yAxis.maxPadding` but that didn't work, because of `min` and `max` were used. I just did not know and found out about `dataLabels.padding`.
Thank you.  :)

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to specify x-offset in plotOptions, but for each series different, see: http://jsfiddle.net/2Ht35/3/

```
        series: [{
            name: 'Male',
            dataLabels: {
                x: -10,
            },
            data: [-3630609, -4312120, -5044512, -5107716, -7236736, -5864184, -4456949, -3506268, -1191588, -122814]
        }, {
            name: 'Female',
            dataLabels: {
                x: 10,
            },
            data: [3443718, 4090246, 4769441, 4821276, 6854069, 5810335, 4730948, 4354576, 2452173, 482710]
        }]
```

Comment: A useful answer indeed, if you would like to set up a specific position/distance for each series individually.
But I prever the more convenient use of `dataLabels.padding`.

Answer (score 0):

One option that i used long back might help you is, placing the svg elements programmatically. Check if this works for you.

```
$.each(chart.series[0].data,function(i,data){

    position = chart.yAxis[0].toPixels(0);


    if(data.y < 0) 
        position-=10;
    else
        position-=70;

    data.dataLabel.attr({
        x:position
    });
});
```

Comment: This is more of a workaround and I wanted to stay as native as possible using highcharts options. But thank you for your effort.

Comment: I give +1, if the answer was helpfull to me.  ;)
Just wanted to be friendly.